# How to deploy a Tomcat application with URL API when using custom context XML

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My application context is defined as an XML file located in `my/path/to/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml`.

```
<Context docBase='/my/path/to/myApp/myAppWarFile.war'>
   <Environment name='my_config_dir' value='/my/path/to/myApp' type='java.lang.String'/>
</Context>
```

`/my/path/to/myApp` contains the WAR file myAppWarFile.war and a number of externalized properties that are read by Spring.

Tomcat is configured with autoDeploy turned off. When I start Tomcat, it creates `my/path/to/Tomcat/conf/webapps/my-app/` and the WAR file gets unpacked into this location as expected, and the application of course can run as expected.

When I want to deploy a new version without restarting Tomcat, I run the undeploy command as follows:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/my-app --user my-username:my-password
```

... and that works. But when I instruct Tomcat to deploy with the following curl statement, I get a failure.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file:/my/path/to/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml --user my-username:my-password
# Tomcat response
FAIL - Invalid context path null was specified
```

Adding the path does not help much, I still get a failure.

```
curl http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?config=file:/my/path/to/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml\&path=/my-app --user my-username:my-password

# Tomcat response
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /my-app
```

The worst part is that tailing catalina.out does not yield any insight. And on top of that, Tomcat deletes the application context XML file `my/path/to/Tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml`!

Naturally I have reviewed Tomcat documentation (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_using_a_Context_configuration_%22.xml%22_file) and I have googled all day to figure this out, but I have not found anything that can help me with this particular configuration.

It feels as though the choice is:

1. Tomcat with autoDeploy on (not recommended for production) in which case simply dropping the new WAR to `/my/path/to/myApp/` will cause Tomcat to hot deploy the app.
2. Tomcat with autoDeploy off, but re-deploying requires a Tomcat restart because the deploy API does not seem to be working as advertised.

Has anybody made this work with this configuration?

EDIT:

I turned up the logging on Catalina. When I run the first deploy command without the path, I get this set of log entries:

```
FINE: Start processing with input [config=file:/my/apth/to/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml]
Oct 13, 2015 10:04:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler process
FINE: Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@189651c1:Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=45415,localport=8080]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
Oct 13, 2015 10:04:53 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
FINE: Error parsing HTTP request header
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout(Http11Processor.java:168)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:982)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Oct 13, 2015 10:04:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler process
FINE: Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper@189651c1:Socket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,port=45415,localport=8080]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
Oct 13, 2015 10:04:53 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch countDown
FINE: Counting down[http-bio-8080-exec-16] latch=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
curl --upload-file /my/path/to/my-app.war http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/my-app --user my-username:my-password
```

Comment: Not yet but I can give it a shot. 

my-app.war is already located on the tomcat server, refreshed by an ansible script. Further, the path and name to the WAR is defined within the tomcat application context XML file. For this reason, I was led to believe that Tomcat would behave the same way as a startup when I use the deploy command.

Comment: Sorry no luck there. From tomcat's manual, "When the optional war parameter is set to the URL for a web application ".war" file or directory it overrides any docBase configured in the context configuration ".xml" file." (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_using_a_Context_configuration_%22.xml%22_file). As I stated in the question, the WAR path is specified in the context configuration XML file.